# Why does Time.parse fail in Rails 4 and 5 but not in Rails 3 for date strings with a space between the date and time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time

In investigating a bug I ran into after upgrading an old Rails 3 app to Rails 4, I noticed that Time.parse fails when this date string contains a space, but parses correctly when the space is removed:

In Rails 3.3.33.5:

```
Time.parse "12/13/2016 3:11 PM"
=> 2016-12-13 15:11:00 -0500
```

But in Rails 4 and 5:

```
Time.parse "12/13/2016 3:11 PM"
ArgumentError: argument out of range
from /Users/diego/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:302:in `local'
```

But if I remove the space between the date and time it works:

```
Time.parse "12/13/20163:11 PM"
=> 2016-12-13 15:11:00 -0500
```

The previous also works in Rails 3. I'm stumped as to what happened between the two versions of Rails that broke Time parse when there's a space between the date and time. Any ideas?

As a solution, because I need to be backwards compatible, I'm rescuing the ArgumentError and gsubbing the space out of the date string and trying again. Is there a better solution for this?

Both examples were done in Ruby 2.2.5

Comment: BTW, I can't reproduce your first example. Are you sure that it works in Rails 3.x? I'm getting an `ArgumentError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, in Rails 4 and later, that string is interpreted as `dd/mm/yyyy` (as it *should*, if you ask me. To hell with `mm/dd/yyyy`).

But if you want that, the proper solution would be to specify the format, not `gsub` random spaces!

```
Time.strptime "12/13/2016 3:11 PM", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'
=> 2016-12-13 15:11:00 -0500
```

Comment: Interesting, but how does that explain the fact that removing the space made it parse successfully?

Comment: @DiegoSalazar: parsing time is very hard. I guess there's a bug or two there. Or maybe it's even a feature.

Comment: There are so many ways to write a time that there has to be conflicts. `mm/dd` `dd/mm` is a good example. It's not a bug, it's information theory.

Comment: @EricDuminil: yes, not talking about `mm/dd` vs `dd/mm`. That ambiguity is unresolvable for cases like `07/12`. But how do we explain that it parses correctly without that space? I, as a human, would not parse that.

Comment: @DiegoSalazar: I vaguely remember reading a post here about exactly this issue (default date format changed with rails upgrade), but can't find it now. :(

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "why", this is what's happening:

```
Date._parse('12/13/2016 3:11 PM')
#=> {:hour=>15, :min=>11, :year=>2016, :mon=>13, :mday=>12}
```

versus:

```
Date._parse('12/13/20163:11 PM')
#=> {:hour=>15, :min=>11, :mon=>12, :mday=>13}
```

Without a space, the year is not recognized as such and `12/13` becomes `mm/dd`.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, handling time is hard. And we're not even dealing with timezones here! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the date is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, you could switch `dd` and `mm` with a regex :

```
Time.parse '12/13/2016 3:11 PM'.sub(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '\2/\1/\3')
```

Comment: I guess it's a matter of personal taste. It did save one whole character though!

Comment: I think it's more than my taste. Now you see _exactly_ how many occurences you're trying to match. As opposed to _counting_ them every time you read the regex.

Comment: Also you can use alternate regex delimiters and save on escaping slashes `%r[(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})]` :)

Comment: Downvoter: feel free to explain why. This code works and answers the question just fine.